# using dropzonejs to upload images to firebase storage?

Tags: dropzone.js, firebase-storage

I am looking for a way to use  [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to upload images to firebase storage. On regular way without dropzone it is no problem. but i like the functionalities of dropzonejs and want to use it.

I would appriciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is possible without ripping out the upload internals of dropzone and replace them with our uploader. The other option would be to set up your own server and use a GCS uploader to upload to Firebase Storage.